# Checking if a file exists in the user's home directory

Tags: ruby, configuration-files

How would I, say, determine if the file `~/.my_proj_config` exists on any OS in Ruby?

Answer (score 21):

A call to [Dir.home](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html#M000628) is a OS independent way to get to the home directory for the user.  You can then use it like

```
File.exists?(File.join(Dir.home, ".my_proj_config"))
```

Comment: What version of ruby are you using?  It is defined at http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-home

Answer (score 3):

This works in Ruby 1.9, but note that the call to `expand_path` is required on some systems (e.g. Windows):

```
File.exists?( File.expand_path "~/.my_proj_config" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the class [File](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html) and its method `exist?`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `Pathname` class, specifically the `realpath` function - This will get you the full (expanded) path to your file.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/classes/Pathname.html#M001991

You then use the `File` class along with `exists?` method to find out if that exists. You shouldn't need to use `realpath` if you use this method, however.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M000045

Comment: I was more wondering if '~' is an acceptable way to find the user's directory from any OS?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes, the tilde has consistent behaviour cross-platform if you're using 1.9. See this commit to the codebase which adds functionality: http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/repositories/diff/ruby-19?rev=21312

Comment: Your statement appears not to be true. On Windows, using Ruby 1.9.2p180, I see: `File.exists?("~/tmp.rb")#=>false` but `File.exists?(File.join(Dir.home,'tmp.rb'))#=>true`. If you put in `File.expand_path` it works (see my answer).

Comment: Pathname#realpath does not do tilde (~) expansion. In fact, there's not a single instance of a tilde in the entire Pathname doc, which is disappointing, since it's supposed to be the new awesome.